# Data Structures programming algorithm

Tags: c

In computer science, a data structure is a particular way of organizing data in a computer so that it can be used efficiently. My program has got errors when compiled on TurboC++. It is on thelearningpoint.net. It has 6 errors. Debug it. Kindly explain the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node
{int data;
struct Node *next;
struct Node *prev;
}node;

void insert(node *pointer, int data)
{ while(pointer->next!=NULL)
  {pointer=pointer->next;
   }
 pointer->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 (pointer->next)->prev=pointer;
 pointer=pointer->next;
 pointer->data=data;
 pointer->next=NULL;
}

void delete(node*pointer,int data)
{ while(pointer->next!=NULL && (pointer->next)->data!=data)
  {pointer=pointer->next;
   }
 if(pointer->next==NULL)
 {printf("Element %d not present",data);
  return;
 }
  node *temp;
  temp=pointer->next;
  pointer->next=temp->next;
  temp->prev=pointer;
  free(temp);
  return;
 }

int main()
{node *start,*temp;
 start=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
 temp=start;
 temp->next=NULL;
 temp->prev=NULL;
 printf("1.Insert");
 printf("2.Delete");

 while(1)
{ int query;
  scanf("%d",&query);
  if(query==1)
 {int data;
  scanf("%d",&data);
  insert(start,data);
 }
else if(query==2)
{int data;
scanf("%d",&data);
delete(start,data);
}
} }
```

Comment: what is the question? Note that this is not a site where others do your homework

Comment: Please include your code in the question instead of linking (and if you do post links, please make sure they show up as links) and describe both how you compile it and what the errors are.

Answer (score 0):

that's because there is a function called delete on line 38 but delete is a keyword in c++, rename the function!

EDIT:

as pointed out by my commenter you can also use the proper compiler

Comment: This is clearly C though. Granted, the OP may be trying to compile it using a C++ compiler, but in that case I'd say the proper solution would be to use the right compiler, not renaming the function.